# Restrict Android App in Play Store for devices supporting Bluetooth LE Advertising

Tags: android, google-play, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-manifest, ads

I am developing an Android App which uses Bluetooth (BLE) Advertising for one of its core features. My Application was rejected by Google because the core feature does not work on some devices.

I could find in internet that not all devices supporting *bluetooth_le* feature do 
support as well BLE Advertising. There is a way how to detect Bluetooth Advertising at run time, I use that to display a 'sorry - not supported' message to the user, still this was a reason to reject the application from store.

So I would like to restrict in Manifest file the application only to the devices supporting BLE in peripheral mode (supporting advertising) so the application will not be rejected due to failing functionality.

If this is not possible, do you know how to handle such cases at runtime? The application will be useless without BLE Advertising but I need to pass the Google acceptance somehow.. Thanks

Comment: This isn't a solution to your problem, but as a temporary workaround if there aren't many devices which support bluetooth but not advertising then you could just blacklist the troublesome devices. See the docs here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455 Hopefully someone else can give you a better solution though

Comment: Thanks for the link! According to the document this is the recommended way by google to avoid crashes on unsupported devices so it is probably the correct way how to achieve my goal. It will we hard though to find out what devices are really supported as I have no possibility to test it on real devices.